# Multicolumn vspace

Tags: multicol, columns

I am trying to make a trifold brochure, and `vspace` is proving ineffective.

Given:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicol*}{3}

\vspace{2.5in}
\hline
\blindtext
\hline
\columnbreak

\end{multicol*}
\end{document}
```

It appears how I would expect if I had put in the `multicol*` environment:

```
\hline
\vfill
\blindtext
\hline
\columnbreak
```

with the text at the bottom of the page. How do I make `vspace` in `multicol*` appear normally?

Comment: `\hline` should not (cannot) be used outside of tabulars or arrays. You want something like `\rule{<width>}{<height of rule>}`.

Comment: You will be better of with `leaflet` class for producing brochures.

Comment: I didn't know about `leaflet`. I was only able to find `brochure`. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The goal of this question is not clear, but I think this does what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{3}
\vspace*{2.5in}%  <-- better, perhaps
% \null\vspace{2.5in}
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}
\blindtext
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}
\vfill
\columnbreak
\blindtext
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

(Note the package is called `multicol` while you `\begin` and `\end` `multicols` environments.)

Comment: Sorry if the question was vague. The goal is to have a vertical spacer that works in a multicolumn environment, something which you successfully accomplished. Thank you for the response.   

Also, you typo'ed the package. The environment is `multicols`, but the package is `multicol`.

Comment: @hxtk -- Ah, right. I copied that line from your question.  It is fixed now....

Comment: Oh dear.... I'll fix that on mine, too. Do you mind explaining why the addition of \null makes \vspace work properly?

Comment: @hxtk -- The non-technical way to think about it is  that `\vspace` needs something to push off of, which makes me realize that `\vspace*{2.5in}` would be better because the starred version of the command (just like `\hspace` vs `\hspace*`) adds space that is never eliminated while the non-starred version adds space that is, by design and usefully, ignored around page boundaries.  Regular `\vspace` adds space only at the end of a line or between paragraphs (which is its normal use).  Try writing `This use of\vspace{1in} \verb+\vspace+ causes a strange gap in this paragraph of text.` to see.